# OnTouchListener not working properly in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, ontouchlistener

I am building an app with fragment. I have one ImageView java file in that I am displaying only image.

When we click on image it will close that particular fragment and open the previous fragment.
Working fine...!!! (For image I have used **onClickListener**)

But when I click on that view it goes two fragments back. (For view I have used **onTouchListener**)

The code is:

```
View v1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.attachment_image, null);
        v1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                return true;        
            }
        });
```

Comment: in place of setOnTouchListener, use setOnClickListener for your image View.

Comment: @Techfist thnx buddy..!
It worked..

Comment: welcome, please vote up my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
View v1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.attachment_image, null);
Imageview image = (Imageview) v1.findViewById(R.id.img_blabla);

image.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        }
});
```

Comment: Why you only provide him the code but no explanation about what he did wrong? Something like "Your method getting called at least two times, 1x for touching down, 1x for lifting your finger up and x times for moving your finger while holding it down" ?